# If NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest fails how do I retry?

Tags: ios, networking

I am using the function `NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest completionHandler` to send async requests using NSURLConnection.

When this fails, how do I retry the same request? What are the best practices around this?

Comment: I guess it depends of the requests and the error. Is it something mandatory for your app ? Can your app works without it ?

Answer (score 2):

When you call the 
`sendAsynchronousRequest`you can and should pass a completion handler block to the function. When the request is finished the completion handler gets called with a NSURLResponse,NSData and an NSError object. Just check if the error is nil and you know that your request finished successfully.
Take a look at the documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:

However if you are developing for iOS9 you should use NSURLSession to make asynchronous network requests because the method in NSURLConnection is deprecated in iOS9 .
Here the link to the class reference of NSURLSession:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/

Comment: Hi @ok404 but if the error is not nil, is there a way I can retry the request? I am using competionHandler when calling sendAsynchronosRequest..

Comment: Yes you can make an if statement in your completion handler and when the request failed you can call the method sendAsynchronousRequest again.
If you don't want duplicated code you can define the completion handler block somewhere in your class.